# Wrap react component correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to wrap the following function that returns BusinessReviewsCardContainer which renders business cards

Current Code

```
const renderIfData = ( lineup ) => {
    if ( lineup ) {
        return lineup[0].competitors.map( ( competitor) => {
            return  <BusinessReviewsCardContainer key={competitor._globalId} data={competitor} />
        });
    } else {
        return <h4>No reviews yet!</h4>;
    }
};

export const LineupsReputation = ( { lineup } ) => (
    <div>
            { renderIfData( lineup ) }
    </div>
);
```

I would like to wrap `<BusinessReviewsCardContainer key={competitor._globalId} data={competitor} />`

With the following so it renders all the business card in the slider

```
<Slider {...settings}>
</Slider>
```

Comment: I think part of the question is missing, the one after "I would like to wrap". Could you please update the question so that it's clear what's your current code and what kind of result you want to get?

Comment: Just update, that is all my code not sure whats not clear?

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: I need to add <Slider {...settings}> </Slider> in the rederIf Data

Comment: you want to warp each BusinessReviewsCardContainer with slider or all BusinessReviewsCardContainer with one Slider ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct